# How to configure SublimeLinter to enforce pep8 errors?

Tags: sublimetext2, lint, pep8

I am trying to get SublimeLinter to enforce pep8 errors as a plugin to sublime text 2. When I install it, it seems to immediately show a small list of errors, but not nearly the full list that I get by running

```
pep8 file.py
```

If I look in my sublime text 2 console, then i see the full list of pep8 errors. However, I want these to be shown in the sublime text 2 gui, when you go to "Show Error List."

If I go to "Show Error List," it says I have no lint errors, but I see hundreds of lint errors in the console.

In the package configuration file it has pep8 set to true by default, but doesnt seem to be enforcing all of the errors.

For someone who has used this plugin, how can I get it to list all of the pep8 errors from the main "Show Error List" window instead of the console?

===

Update: After a while of poking around, I have narrowed down. In the SublimeLinter plugin (file python.py) there is a line:

```
    pep8.Checker(filename, good_lines).check_all()
```

This is what actually runs pep8 on the file. When it encounters an error it is supposed to call the `pep8.Checker.report_error` function, and there is a custom callback defined in the plugin. However, I have traced it, and I see that it is not being called. The checker is running correctly and producing out. I have examined the pep8 code here https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/blob/master/pep8.py, but no luck.

I imagine there is a very simple fix... probably a configuration somewhere. If anyone has insights, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Based on the description this sounds more like a bug in SublimeLinter which you might want to patch out than a configuration. Try to file an issue and a patch on Github?

Comment: I would try and patch it if I had figured it out, but right now I just switched to a different plugin. The thing that was odd was that it displayed some errors, but not all of them, and I couldn't find the exact problem